# onclick change/restore container content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/ox5xq082/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>




        </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> Profile Page</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> User Info </h3>
                        <p>
                            <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
                            <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.email %><br>
                            <strong>Username</strong>: <%= user.local.username %><br>
                            <strong>Country</strong>: <%= user.local.country %><br>
                            <strong>Region</strong>: <%= user.local.region %><br>
                            <hr>
                            <strong>Food</strong>: <%= user.local.inventory.food %><br>
                            <strong>Energy Drinks</strong>: <%= user.local.inventory.energyDrinks %><br>
                            <hr>
                            <strong>Eur</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.eur.toFixed(2) %><br>
                            <strong>Gold</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.gold.toFixed(2) %><br>
                            <strong>Silver</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.silver.toFixed(3) %><br>
                            <hr>
                            <strong>Estate</strong>: <% if (user.local.estate.movedIn === true) { %>
                                                        Owned
                                                    <% } else if (user.local.estate.rented.movedIn === true) { %>
                                                        Renting from <%= user.local.estate.rented.rentedFrom %>
                                                    <% } else { %>
                                                        No Office Owned or Rented
                                                    <% } %><br>
                            <hr>
                            <strong>Energy</strong>: <%= user.local.energy.toFixed(2) %>%<br>

                        </p>

                        <hr>
                        <button id="shop" class="btn btn-primary">Shop</button>
                        <button id="duel" class="btn btn-primary">Duel</button>
                        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Center Page -->
            <div id="center-div" class="col-md-9">
                <div class="container">
                        default content
                    <div id="duel-window" style="width=100% height=100%"> duel content 
                        <span id="pp_close" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

                    </div>
                    <div id="shop-window" style="width=100% height=100%"> shop content
                        <span id="pp_close" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

                    </div>
                <div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
    $('#duel').click(function() {

        $('#duel-window').css("display","block")
    });
    $('#shop').click(function() {

     $('#shop-window').css("display","block")
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css

```
    html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    #user-info {
        float: left;
        display: none;
    }


    #center-div {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border: #e3e3e3;
        height : 595px;

    }

    #duel-window {
        display:none;
    }
    #shop-window {
        display:none;
    }
    #pp_close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        color: red;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
```

I want to be able to change just the content of center-div container. If I press Shop button it should change to shop content and when I press duel it should change to duel content. When I press the pp_close button it should go back to default content. How would I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you fiddle this?

Comment: @SushangNirola Done

Comment: @Aziz Well, I googled around replaceWith() seems like a good option but I do have a lot a code and that seems like it's meant for short code replacement unless I found only simple examples. The other way I found is to somehow use display block/none and that's what I want but was not able to reproduce it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many buttons and want much cleaner code follow these steps

**HTML:**

1. add pp-close class and set different ids on ppCloses
2. add each of your buttons a class named `content-trigger` to bind click event
3. add each of you buttons a custom attribute named `target-id` that keeps the target content element id(`target-id="#duel-window"`).
4. add each of your contents a class named `avalible-content`

your html should look likes this:

```
<button id="shop" target-id="#shop-window" class="btn btn-primary content-trigger">Shop</button>
<button id="duel" target-id="#duel-window" class="btn btn-primary content-trigger">Duel</button>
<div class="container">
                default content
            <div id="duel-window" class="avalible-content" style="width=100% height=100%"> duel content 
                <span id="pp_close"  class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove pp-close"></span>

            </div>
            <div id="shop-window" class="avalible-content" style="width=100% height=100%"> shop content
                <span id="pp_close1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove pp-close"></span>

            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

1. use `show() and hide()` to show or hide elements.
2. use `.content-trigger` selector to bind all buttons onclick at once
3. use `target-id` attribute to show the corresponding content
4. use `$(".avalible-content").hide();` to hide all contents before showing new one.

   ```
    $(".pp-close").click(function() {
       $("#shop-window").hide();
       $('#duel-window').hide();
    });

    $(".content-trigger").click(function(e) {
       $(".avalible-content").hide();
       var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr("target-id");
       $(target).show();
    });
   ```

**CSS: add #pp_close1 to css**

```
#pp_close,#pp_close1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   color: red;
   font-size: 25px;
}
```

a working sample [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/ox5xq082/3/)

Comment: Same question as above: How about if I  have 10 buttons, is this still the ideal way to go ?

Comment: @Trax, I updated the answer for adding many button/contents with minimal  coding

Comment: Perfect, had to modify it a bit so it hides default content when another content is present and restore it on pp_close. Other than that it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shop').on('click',function(){
        $('#shop-window').show();
        $('#dual-window').hide();
    })
    $('#dual').on('click',function(){
        $('#shop-window').hide();
        $('#dual-window').show();
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#shop').on('click',function(){
  $('#shop-window').show();
    $('#dual-window').hide();
})
$('#dual').on('click',function(){
  $('#shop-window').hide();
    $('#dual-window').show();
})
})
```

```css
.formValidateError {
    color:#FF0000;  /* red */
}
.formValidateValid {
    color:#00CC00; /* green */
 
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#user-info {
 float: left;
 display: none;
}


#center-div {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
 border: #e3e3e3;
 height : 595px;

}

#duel-window {
 display:none;
}
#shop-window {
 display:none;
}
#pp_close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
 color: red;
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
  <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>

 
 
 
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> Profile Page</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="well">
                <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> User Info </h3>
                    <p>
                        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
                        <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.email %><br>
                        <strong>Username</strong>: <%= user.local.username %><br>
      <strong>Country</strong>: <%= user.local.country %><br>
      <strong>Region</strong>: <%= user.local.region %><br>
      <hr>
      <strong>Food</strong>: <%= user.local.inventory.food %><br>
      <strong>Energy Drinks</strong>: <%= user.local.inventory.energyDrinks %><br>
      <hr>
      <strong>Eur</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.eur.toFixed(2) %><br>
      <strong>Gold</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.gold.toFixed(2) %><br>
      <strong>Silver</strong>: <%= user.local.budget.silver.toFixed(3) %><br>
      <hr>
      <strong>Estate</strong>: <% if (user.local.estate.movedIn === true) { %>
             Owned
            <% } else if (user.local.estate.rented.movedIn === true) { %>
             Renting from <%= user.local.estate.rented.rentedFrom %>
            <% } else { %>
             No Office Owned or Rented
            <% } %><br>
      <hr>
      <strong>Energy</strong>: <%= user.local.energy.toFixed(2) %>%<br>
      
                    </p>
    
     <hr>
     <button id="shop" class="btn btn-primary">Shop</button>
     <button id="duel" class="btn btn-primary">Duel</button>
     <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
 <!-- Center Page -->
  <div id="center-div" class="col-md-9">
   <div class="container">
     default content
    <div id="duel-window" style="width=100% height=100%"> duel content 
     <span id="pp_close" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    
    </div>
    <div id="shop-window" style="width=100% height=100%"> shop content
     <span id="pp_close" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    
    </div>
   <div>
  </div>
  
    </div>

</div>
<script>
$('#duel').click(function() {

 $('#duel-window').css("display","block")
});
$('#shop').click(function() {

 $('#shop-window').css("display","block")
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I can work with this. However I intend having a lot more buttons/content for that area would it be an issue. Ideally I'm looking for a way to just replace the same position instead of using show/hide.